# Javascript returns me wrong day

Tags: javascript, date

I have to write function which determines which day of week particular date is. I wrote following code, but it returns in 99% cases wrong day. Can you explain me why?

```
var day = 1, month = 1, year = 2016;

function whatDay(day, month, year) {
    var myDate = new Date();
    myDate.setFullYear(year);
    myDate.setMonth(month);
    myDate.setDate(day);

    console.log( myDate.getDay() );
}

whatDay(day, month, year);
```

Comment: `getDay` returns day of the week..

Comment: I think you should write `myDate.getDate();`

Comment: Are you looking for 2016/01/01 (New Year day)? `month = 0`. Months go from `0` (January) to `11` (December), not `1...12` as one would expect.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are confused as to how the [getDay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) works. See the docs:

> The getDay() method returns the day of the week for the specified date
>   according to local time, **where 0 represents Sunday**.

So the day starts from 0 index representing Sunday. 1 as Monday and so on based on the local time.

Just to add, that similarly the months are also indexed from 0. So 0 is for January and so on.

Answer (score 3):

> which day of week particular date

It seems you are looking for weekday like Sunday,Monday & so on.+

If it is so then following snippet can be useful

```
var day = 1, month = 1, year = 2016;

function whatDay(day, month, year) {
    var myDate = new Date();
    myDate.setFullYear(year);
    myDate.setMonth(month);
    myDate.setDate(day);

   var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[4] = "Thursday";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";

   var n = weekday[myDate.getDay()]
   console.log(n); //Monday
}

whatDay(day, month, year);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/2d8hveuv/)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I know how getDay() works, however I didn't know that it counts months from 0 to 11. Thanks @Amadan